# How to display array in table on Android

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have class Like

```
public class Items {
    public int icon;
    public String label;
    public String price;
    public String offer;
    public Items(){
        super();
    }

    public Items(int icon, String label,String price,String offer) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.label = label;
        this.price = price;
        this.offer = offer;
    }
}
```

And I created objects for that class like

```
Items items_data[] = new Items[]
{
new Items(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Samsung","400","Hot Item"),
new Items(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Samsung1","4001","Hot Item1"),

};
```

Now i need to display the above value in table row like In first row i have to display the first position and so on..
please help.

Comment: Use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) to present your data in table-like view, the link contains everything you need to know.

Comment: Do you want to display this in `ListView` or in `TableLayout` with `TableRow`s?

Comment: yes i want to display it with tablelayout and also the table rows and columns are created based on the length of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
Items items_data[] = new Items[] {
    new Items(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Samsung", "400", "Hot Item"),
    new Items(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Samsung1", "4001", "Hot Item1"),
};

TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);

for (Items items : items_data) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(items.icon);
    tr.addView(iv);

    TextView label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText(items.label);
    tr.addView(label);

    TextView price = new TextView(this);
    price.setText(items.price);
    tr.addView(price);

    TextView offer = new TextView(this);
    offer.setText(items.offer);
    tr.addView(offer);

    tl.addView(tr);
}

your_layout.add(tl);
```

Comment: It works but it shows in a single column only..If I have 9 records means it has to show in a 3 rows and 3 colums

Comment: When you add a view in `TableRow` it adds every view in the next column. So, this code crates a table with two rows with four columns each. I think what you want to do is show borders between rows and columns. If you want to do this you have to add a border background in the drawable folder. Search, you can find how to do this easily. And after that, apply this drawable as background of every view.